# How does reentrantlock in Java ensure memory visibility？

Tags: java, locking, volatile, barrier

Some people think it depends on the internal volatile type of 'state' variable, but I don't agree.
Because as I understand it, the volatile keyword only guarantees that volatile variables (and not all common variables before the keyword) are written and visible to multiple threads.

My question comes from the code of CopyOnWriteArrayList.when add method is called,the CopyOnWriteArrayList make the code of critical area visible for other threads using lock.So,how does reentrantlock ensure them visible

```
    public boolean add(E e) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        Object[] elements = getArray();
        int len = elements.length;
        Object[] newElements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, len + 1);
        newElements[len] = e;
        setArray(newElements);
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's best to read up on section 17.4 of the Java Language Specification (Java Memory Model). Your understanding is not correct - a write to a volatile variable "happens-before" a read of the same volatile variable, meaning that all actions (all writes) that happened before the volatile write are seen by a different thread that reads that same volatile variable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

Comment: I mean ,it is the volatile variable once wriiten can be seen by diffierent thread. Common variables before volatile still cannot be see.It's wrong?

Comment: Give us the code part, you think has a problem. The whole reentrantlock could be very complicated to explain.

Comment: My question comes from the code of CopyOnWriteArrayList.when add method is called,the CopyOnWriteArrayList make the code of critical area visible for other threads using lock.So,how does reentrantlock ensure them visible

Comment: It is because reading from a volatile variable makes **all writes** visible from another thread that wrote to that volatile variable earlier (that's the very short summary - read JLS 17.4 for the full details). You're wrong about not seeing "common variables", reading from a volatile variables makes all writes (including those to non-volatile variables) visible from the thread that wrote to the volatile variable.